# append new DataSource to the existing one in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to append a `List<T>` to an existing `DataSource` for a `DataGridView`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Below is a code example of what I tried.

```
var acList = new List<Account>();
for (int i = 0; i < gridAcearch.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(gridAcearch.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
    {
        try
        {
            string accountId = gridAcearch.Rows[i].Cells["accountIds"].Value.ToString();
            acList.Add(db.Accounts.Where(x => x.accountId == accountId).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
if (gridOpenBalance.Rows.Count <= 1)
{
    bindS = new BindingSource();
    bindS.DataSource = acList;
    var source = new BindingSource(bindS, null);
    gridOpenBalance.DataSource = source;
}
else
{
    //here I want to add new aclist to the existing one in the grid ,
    //if I added it immediately the previous rows in the grid gets deleted and new ones gets added
    //I used this code but it doesn't work , If there something like


    var bindS = new BindingList<Account>(acList)
                var source = gridOpenBalance.DataSource;

    //if there is something work this way  


    bindS.DataSource = acList + gridOpenBalance.DataSource;
    bindS.DataSource = acList;
    source = new BindingSource(bindS, null);
    gridOpenBalance.DataSource = source;
}
```

Comment: You can simply add data to the BindingSource. It exposes an `Add()` method (adds data to the internal BindingList).

Comment: in if statement when I used bindS.DataSource = acList; works fine but when I use bindS.Add(acList); this error occurs System.InvalidOperationException: 'Objects added to a BindingSource's list must all be of the same type.' infact the grid dataBind is not the same type as the acList

Comment: You need to loop the elements in `acList` and use the `Add()` method to add each new element. You cannot add elements in batch to a BindingList (the internal list of your BindingSource).

Comment: This where I was stucked, worked fine , Thank You Jimi you can post your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

- Make a class property `private List<Account> dataList = new List<Account>();`.
- Add your result to that list.
- Use `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` and `dataGridView1.Refresh();` to clear you view
- Load `dataList` as the new source

That might be inefficient but maybe it helps you to get unstuck.

Comment: Thank you , if new data list added the previouse one gets deleted, I want a way to append new data to existing DataGridView's rows , the code in "If" works fine if it is first time